# RCP (Remote Copy Protocol) in Ubuntu

Tags: cisco, rsync, copy

On our Cisco-Routers we enabled RCP. Now we want copy all the running-config with our Ubuntu Server but I can't find any suitable command.

I tried copying with rsync and cp but that did not work.

Commands I tried:

```
cp (IP):running-config
rsync (IP):running-config ./
rsync rcp://10.18.253.1/running-config ./
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RCP is not the same as scp or cp or rsync. It's [rcp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rcp_(Unix)). The command that you would use, if it were installed, is `rcp`.

---

rcp is packaged and distributed with `rsh`, and often with `kerberos`.

Comment: I can't find any package, where can I get it?

Comment: Did you check to see what happens when you issue the "sudo apt-get install rcp" command?

Comment: @Xarem add'l information added

Comment: Thank you, it's in the rsh-package (aptitude install rsh)!

Answer (score 2):

Others have already explained what rcp for unix is.

If you want to automatically save your routers/switches configs, take a look at [rancid](http://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/). It works a treat. It keeps a revision history of all the configs. It works great in debian, so I guess it will with ubuntu too.

Answer (score 1):

RCP is is part of the unix rshell suite of programs and is accessed through the `rcp` command. It can be used for copying files and directories from one system to another. You can find it's manpage [**here**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rcp) and some examples [**here**](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_rcp.htm).

Rsync can also be used for copying files and directories from one system to another. It has built in protocols that can be used to keep directories on different systems in sync with each other whilst keeping the amount of network traffic to a minimum.  The rsync manpage is [**here**](http://www.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html) and there are examples of it's use [**here**](http://www.samba.org/rsync/examples.html).

Comment: rsh/rcp is also ancient, apart from cases as described where appliance hardware does not support anything else you should use ssh/scp.